# Integral mean of non decreasing function is non decreasing

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Given a continuous non decreasing function $r(t)$ prove that $\frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{t} r(s)ds$ is also non decreasing.

**Attempt**

Non decreasingness for continuous functions would imply that the derivative is non negative therefore we start with $r'(t) \ge 0$ and take the derivative of the integral mean we get $r(t) - \frac{1}{t^2}\int_{0}^{t}r(s)ds$ but it's unclear to me how to prove that it is greater or equal than 0.

Comment: The claim is wrong. Take $r(t)=e^t$. You will see that the integral mean of that is $e^t/t$ which is decreasing on $t\in[0,1]$.

Comment: @Kurt but $\frac{e^t-1}{t}$ is.increasing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $f'$ is increasing and $f(0)=0$, then $f(x)/x$ is increasing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333664/if-f-is-increasing-and-f0-0-then-fx-x-is-increasing)

Comment: @zwim . Thanks . +1 .

Comment: @zwim I don't think it does, not sure if they can be connected somehow

Comment: @Mattiatore It obviously does, letting $f(x)=\int_0^xr$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivative of the integral mean is
$$\tag{1}
\frac{r(t)}{t}-\frac{\int_0^tr(s)\,ds}{t^2}
$$
(in your corresponding formula is an error). Since $r$ is non decreasing we have
$$
\frac{1}{t}\int_0^tr(s)\,ds\le\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t r(t)\,ds=r(t)\,.
$$
Therefore (1) is bounded from below by
$$
\frac{r(t)}{t}-\frac{r(t)}{t}=0
$$
which implies that the integral mean is non decreasing.